# convert yyyymmdd date format into yyddd ordinal date in R

Tags: r, date, formatting

Using R, I am trying to convert some dates into yyddd ordinal date format (e.g. 2010-12-31 to 10365), but I am not successful since I got values that are wrong.

Here is an working example.

```
dates<-as.data.frame(c("20040101", "20040102", "20040103", 
                   "20041229", "20041230", "20041231"))
cols <- "date"
colnames(dates) <- cols

dates$date.format1<- as.Date(as.character(dates$date), "%Y%m%d")
dates$date.format2<- strptime(dates$date.format1, "%y%j")
```

What I was expecting is 04001, 04002, 04003, 04363, 04364, 04365

Any help will be really appreciated.

Best regards,

Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if we replace `strptime` with `format`:

```
> format(as.Date(dates$date, "%Y%m%d"), "%y%j")
[1] "04001" "04002" "04003" "04364" "04365" "04366"
```

**Note:** We used as input:

```
dates <- data.frame(date = c("20040101", "20040102", "20040103", 
                             "20041229", "20041230", "20041231"))
```